# Making product, pricing, shipping calculator with data from other website

Tags: php

I am making a product pricing and shipping calculator which will work from the data fetched by another shopping website. I got little bit of success it is showing product image, product price, name of product and status of product. But shipping system is not working because that website is using Javascript.
I am using htmldom! and targeted website is: **BANGGOOD.COM**

**INDEX PAGE**

```
<form method="get" action="url_look.php">
<input type="text" placeholder="Banggood.com Product URL" name="keywords"/><input type="submit"  value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**URL LOOK PAGE**

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$keywords = str_replace(" ","-",$_GET['keywords']);
$url =  "$keywords";
$html = file_get_html($url);
echo "<div>";
foreach($html->find('div[class=item_box price],h1[itemprop=name],div[class=good_photo_max],div[class=status],div[class=item_box shipping]') as $product_title){
//for more details visit http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.html
echo "<li>".$product_title."</li>";
}
echo "</div>";
?>
<style>
ul {
 display: none;
}
li {
list-style: none;
}
</style>
```

Above code was provided by a stackoverflow member: Aqueel Aboobacker VP and now i modified his code to make a pricing, and shipping calculator.

Basically i want to show price and then people select shipping methods which will be fetch from Banggood.com and then total will appear in USD. note that each product on banggood have different shipping methods and different prices depends on country

Comment: **Bang good** oh my god what a name

Comment: Current result is here: http://mybtc.website/test

Answer (score 0):

Problem is more complicated. For example for this product:

http://www.banggood.com/Original-Xiaomi-16000mAh-Universal-Battery-Charger-Power-Bank-p-953908.html

When product site is loading, you browser create async request using URL: http://www.banggood.com/index.php?com=product&t=initShipments&products_id=953908

This URL return information about shipping. First URL has product id (for example 953908) and next request building URL using this product id.

Comment: Hmm, it is bit hard to do.. also website don't allow iframes

Comment: Hmm why you are using iframes? You should parse response from second URL.